# Symfony Doctrine Query For Many to Many Releationships

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I have Many to Many relationship between Institutes and Courses. I want to build query that returns only the institutes list whom some courses has been assigned. I have wrote queries in this situation for `one to many`. but for not `many to many`.  here is the relationships,

```
class Institutes { 

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Courses", inversedBy="institutes")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="institute_courses",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="institute_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $courses;
}

class Courses {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Institutes", mappedBy="courses")
     */
    protected $institutes;
}
```

here is the query that i have written, but didn't work properly.

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->leftJoin('CoursesBundle:Courses','c', 'ON c.institutes = s.courses')
                        ->where('s.active = :active')
                        ->andWhere('s.verified = :active')
                        ->setParameter('active', true)
                        ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC');
```

Comment: try to replace the leftJoin by an innerJoin if you want to be sure to target only the institutes with courses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->innerJoin('i.courses','c')
    ->where('i.active = TRUE')
    ->andWhere('i.verified = TRUE')
    ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC');
```

Comment: No, Not wokring it returns all institutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` as you would with other kinds of associations. The following query will find all courses which have been assigned at least to one institute:

```
SELECT c FROM SomeBundle:Courses c JOIN c.institutes i
```

You can filter the results further by adding a join condition:

```
SELECT c FROM SomeBundle:Courses c JOIN c.institutes i WITH i.something = :someParam
```

Comment: Hmm. Missed that. Then change the query accordingly. I've already showed you *how* to do this.